# Keras Subgraphs TensorFlow Lite

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, arduino, tensorflow-lite

I am developing a Deep Learning Model that is converted into a TensorFlow Lite Model and loaded onto an Arduino. A limitation of the Arduino TensorFlow Lite Library is that it does not allow more than one subgraph.

Comment: What Arduino model do you want to run this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it looks like your model didn't use TFLite LSTM op.

If you leveraged TFLite LSTM op, then you should have 1 subgraph, which should solve your problem.

This [colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/experimental_new_converter/Keras_LSTM_fusion_Codelab.ipynb#scrollTo=IQtjKcMYC_nD) has an end to end example for building and converting model with LSTM.

Please check it, if you still have problem let us know with more details on how you convert your model.